# Integrating QNX Qt libraries in a Qt project

Tags: qt, qnx

Would anyone know how to include/use the QNX Qt libraries such as QtQnxCar2, QPPS, QPlayer in a Qt project? I think this involves including a package in Qt or may be linking the library in the .pro file, just can't figure out what it is though.

QNX has lot of [documentation](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/660/topic/com.qnx.doc.qt/topic/qt_dev_tools.html?cp=2_5_3_0) about the libraries, but nothing about how to actually include and use them in a Qt project.

I am specifically looking for how to use the [Qpps](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/660/topic/com.qnx.doc.qt/topic/qpps_api/qpps_api.html?cp=2_5_3_3) namespace in my project. For example, I've linked the qpps library as below in my .pro file:

```
LIBS += -L/home/me/qnx660/target/qnx6/armle-v7/qtcar/lib/ -lqpps
INCLUDEPATH += /home/me/qnx660/target/qnx6/armle-v7/qtcar
DEPENDPATH += /home/me/qnx660/target/qnx6/armle-v7/qtcar
```

Here's the code in mainwindow.cpp,

```
#include <QDebug>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QTimer>
using namespace QPps;
```

Here's the build error:

```
mainwindow.cpp:5:17: error: 'QPps' is not a namespace-name
mainwindow.cpp:5:21: error: expected namespace-name before ';' token
cc: /home/me/qnx660/host/linux/x86/usr/lib/gcc/arm-unknown-nto-qnx6.6.0eabi/4.7.3/cc1plus error 1
make: *** [mainwindow.o] Error 1
```

Toolchain: 
Qt Creator 3.3.2 
Qt 5.2.0 
QNX Car 2.1 
QNX SDP 6.6 
Ubuntu
14.04

Comment: It is a compiler problem, not linker. Pls. see my modified answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**
The question is changed completely! Instead of linking problem, described earlier, now a compiler error is described.
You have to include the header-file first, where the namespace is declared.
e.g:

```
#include <qpps/changeset.h>
```

Also, pay attention, that the directory of qpps-include files (headers, .h-files) are defined in the line:

```
INCLUDEPATH += <Path to your qpps includes >
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**
If QNX libraries apply to the same rules as other UNIX libraries, you could use them by including this line in your Qt project file (*.pro)

```
LIBS += -L/Path/to/mylib/ -lmylib
```

Actually QNX doesn't have to provide any info, how to use their libs in Qt.
The appropriate manual is the QMAKE-manual.

Comment: I had tried linking it this way too, but didn't work. Thanks anyways.

Comment: could you provide more information, what went wrong? Your makefile, project-file, build system, compiler or linker error?

Comment: it just can't find the library. Please see my modified question again.

Comment: Thanks, but it's still the same question of linking - I should have provided more details from the beginning. The compiler gives error because the lib is not linked correctly.